# Growing plant in a composting terrarium

Tags: compost, terrarium

I was thinking about throwing compostable rubbish into a jar and growing a plant in it while the jar lead is closed as a terrarium before the composting proceeds—and then leave it as it is. I am not sure how much this idea is achievable but here this brings me a few questions that I cannot easily find on google:

- Is this idea functional?
- Can a plant grow in a composting pile before the composting is finished, with a little soil? Does composting damage the root of the plant growing on top of the compost?
- Can composting happen in a closed jar?
- Will the oxygen used by the compost, and the oxygen created by the plant/moss, balance each other?

Comment: it would be a miracle if the decomposers lost the land grab in that case.

Answer (score 2):

"A pile of compostable rubbish" is not "composting". A proper compost pile will kill most living plant material simply because it is too hot. The interior of a working compost pile can reach 50C or 120F.

Composting is an aerobic process, so it won't work in a closed jar. You will just produce a stinky rotten mess.

Comment: I'm guessing a jar wouldn't be large enough to sustain 120 degrees F. from anaerobic compost; if it were, we could probably use such as a cheap and effective heat source (however, it would explode if it were just anaerobic compost; if they survived, I'm not sure if plants/moss would stop that). If something would kill the plants, I'm thinking it would be the ammonia, root rot pathogens, moisture overload, or some such. If it were *much* more soil than compostables (or even no compostables), I would think the odds of success would be improved. I would recommend getting algae to grow in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not composting* - it will not kill pathogens and weeds, it will smell awfully due to ammonia release, it will not attract proper decomposing organisms like bacteria or warms.
2. I do it all the time. But I can't wear it works - wait 10 years and come back.
3. It is acidic. Try to grow something that loves acid shuch as Jalapeño or lilium.

<sub>* - it would help to mix in a carbon source such as ash, embers, straw</sub>